# converting to int from float

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 float const PI = 3.1415926;

int radius = 4;
int peri = 0;
int area = 0;

peri =(float) (PI * 2)* radius;
area = (float) PI * (radius * radius);

cout << "Radius is " << radius << endl;
cout << "Perimeter is " << peri << endl;
cout << "Area is " << area << endl;

return 0;
};
```

peri and area are not converting to float and always receiving a warning "converting to int from float" what seems to be the problem ..

Comment: Because that exactly what you're doing. peri and area are declared as ints, you might want them to be floats, so declare them as floats.

Comment: You can't properly store a `float` in an `int`, any more than you can fit a square peg in a round hole. Declare `peri` and `area` as `float`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to truncate peri and area to integers, you should do so explicitly:

```
peri=static_cast<int>(2*PI*radius);
area=static_cast<int>(PI*radius*radius);
```

Otherwise, you'll get a warning and it will look like a mistake to anyone who reads your code.